# Why am I getting results that don't match the first WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WHERE [SOTR_CUST_CODE] = 'O004'
  AND [SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'PC%'
   OR [SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'PD%'
```

This returns records of customers that are not 'O004', and I'm not sure why. Is there also a better way to search for a string that could start with 2 different sets of characters without using the `LIKE` function twice?

Using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Add parentheses, since AND goes befoer OR: `WHERE [SOTR_CUST_CODE] = 'O004'
  AND ([SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'PC%'
   OR [SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'PD%')`

Comment: Never mix `AND` and `OR` without using parentheses, because the order of evaluation is not what you're expecting. (Ever.)

Comment: OK, I just need to wrap the 2 LIKE functions in parenthesis as this stops the query returning all [SOTD_STRC_CODE] starting with 'PD'.

Is there still a better way to query the [SOTD_STRC_CODE] when i want to find ones starting with either 'PC' or 'PD'?

Comment: You can use a character class: `P[CD]%`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parentheses in your clause. Without parentheses, it means:

(A and B) OR C

Therefore you will get all records matching condition C regardless of condition A or B.

Answer (score 1):

I know it already has very good answer (thanks to Laposhasu Acsa), but wanted to clarify for future readers:

> Below code (without parentheses) is the same as (A and B) or C

```
WHERE [SOTR_CUST_CODE] = 'O004'
  AND [SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'PC%'
   OR [SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'PD%'
```

> First solution is to use parentheses:

```
WHERE [SOTR_CUST_CODE] = 'O004'
  AND ([SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'PC%'
        OR [SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'PD%')
```

> Second solution, which suits this particular case is:

```
WHERE [SOTR_CUST_CODE] = 'O004'
  AND [SOTD_STRC_CODE] LIKE 'P[CD]%'
```